# Multiple DISQUS on the same page?

Tags: ajax, comments, disqus

I need to insert the DISQUS system on a webpage of my website. Thats easy.

The problem here is that I need to insert multiple DISQUS boxes on the same page.

I need something like [this](http://culturadigital.br/marcocivil/debate/). Every article and every paragraph has your own comment block.

Any suggestion? Maybe I need to load the comments using some kind of [API](http://wiki.disqus.net/API) via AJAX?

I'll use this on a page in my WordPress powered site.

Comment: This solution should work too: http://mystrd.at/articles/multiple-disqus-threads-on-one-page/ The collaborable site seems to have gone away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this trick here, it worked for me: <strike>http://collaborable.com/blog/disqus-jquery-hack-awesome-ux</strike>

Unfortunately, the article is no longer available except [via the Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20120603213107/http://collaborable.com/blog/disqus-jquery-hack-awesome-ux).

The relevant portions from that link are as follows. To show / hide comments:

```
<div class="comments">
  <p class="nocomment">
    <a class="nocomment" href="/">Hide comments</a>
  </p>
  <div class="disqus_thread"></div>
</div>
<p class="comment">
  <a class="comment"
    href="http://collaborable.com/blog/blog-entry-title"
    data-disqus-identifier="blog-entry-id">
    <span>Leave a comment</span>
  </a>
</p>
```

...And the corresponding Javascript:

```
     // DISQUS vars.
    var disqus_shortname = 'collaborable';
    var disqus_identifier = '';
    var disqus_url = '';

     // Leave a comment/cancel.
    $('.entry a.comment').click(function () {
        // Firefox? Bad firefox.
        if ($.browser.mozilla && window.disqus_loaded) {
            return true;
        }

        // Init DISQUS.
        disqus_identifier = $(this).data('disqus-identifier');
        disqus_url = $(this).attr('href');

        // DISQUS requires each thread to have the ID #disqus_thread.
        $entry = $(this).parents('div.entry');
        $('#disqus_thread').removeAttr('id');
        $entry.find('div.disqus_thread').attr('id', 'disqus_thread');

        // Load DISQUS script, if not already loaded.
        if ($entry.find('div.disqus_thread .dsq-reply').length == 0) {
            $.getScript('http://' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js',
                function () {
                    window.disqus_interval =
                        setInterval('is_disqus_loaded("' + $entry.attr('id') + '")',
                            200);
                }
            );
        }

        // Hide/kill other DISQUS forums.
        $entry.find('a.nocomment').trigger('click');
        $(this).find('span').addClass('loading');
        return false;

    });

     // Hide/kill all open DISQUS forums.
    $('.entry a.nocomment').click(function () {
        $('div.comments').slideUp('normal',
            function () {
                $(this).find('.disqus_thread').empty();
            });
        $('p.comment').slideDown();
        return false;
    });

    function is_disqus_loaded(entry_id) {
        $entry = $('#' + entry_id);
        if ($entry.find('div.disqus_thread .dsq-reply').length) {
            clearInterval(window.disqus_interval);
            window.disqus_loaded = true;
            $entry.find('div.comments').slideDown();
            $entry.find('a.comment span').removeClass('loading');
            $entry.find('p.comment').slideUp();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Broken link x2. Is this referenced anywhere else?

Answer (score 1):

You may try http://tsi.github.io/inlineDisqussions/
It will give you per-paragraph comment threads powered by Disqus.
Just download the script and the style sheet and include them (after jQuery).
Then call the script like this:

```
<script>
  disqus_shortname = 'your_disqus_shortname';
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("p").inlineDisqussions();
  });
</script>
```

See the linked page for more info.
disclaimer: I wrote this.

Answer (score 0):

This might help. My backend is WordPress/PHP. I use this code in conjunction with Elementor.

This code loads Disqus in separate Iframes 'src'. The page identifier/URL gets pulled by PHP for each individual post.

```
<iframe id="disqus" srcdoc="<div id='disqus_thread'></div>
<script>
    var disqus_config = function () {
    this.page.url = '<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>';  
    this.page.identifier = '<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>'; 
    };

    (function() { // DONT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
    var d = document, s = d.createElement('script');
    s.src = 'https://XXXXXXXX.disqus.com/embed.js';
    s.setAttribute('data-timestamp', +new Date());
    (d.head || d.body).appendChild(s);
    })();
</script>
<noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href='https://disqus.com/?ref_noscript'>comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>" >
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```